# Transfer speed of USB-C to Lightning on latest iPad Pro 10.5

Tags: itunes, ipad, usb, performance, data-transfer

Has anyone experience or estimates on what transfer speeds are to expect when transferring data to/from the latest gen. iPad Pro 10.5 using a USB-C to lightning cable? Scenarios might be

- creating an iTunes backup
- syncing movies, music and other media via iTunes
- copying photos, videos using iTunes or some photo organizer app
- transferring documents to apps using the iTunes app documents feature
- ...

USB 2 is really ancient now, and I expect a modern device as expensive as the iPad to offer faster transfer speeds than USB 2. So it would be great to know if the USB-C to lightning cable is worth buying. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The iPad Pro 10.5"-inch model supports USB 3, so it is not the "ancient" USB 2 as you mention.

USB-C only refers to the plug, so it hasn't got anything specifically to do with the USB-C to Lighting cable - you can achieve the same, higher speeds using a USB-A port when using a USB 3 compatible cable and USB 3 capable port.

Comment: That’s not true. Of course, USB-C refers to the plug, but sadly, it’s the only possible option to reach USB 3 transfer speeds between an iPad and Computer. That’s what I meant by “ancient USB 2.0” - Apple’s Lighning-to-USB-A-cables are still USB 2.0. It’s easy to check, just take a look at the USB-A-connector of those cables, if they were capable of USB 3, they’d need to have extra pins in the connector besides the standard 4 USB 2.0-pins. And they don’t, at least I’ve never seen a standard USB-to-Lightning-cable that did.

Comment: Well, I meant that it is not "USB-C" as such, but ofcourse the whole chain, including the cable needs to be 3.0 compatible. If you use the relevant cables and adapters, you can achieve the high speeds without having a USB-C port in your computer.

Comment: From Apple you can use the USB 3 compatible Camera Adapter to get a USB-A port with USB 3 speeds, or you can use a USB 3 lightning cable from a different maker than Apple.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your efforts. Then it was proably a misunderstanding. I already own the new Apple Camera Adapter with USB 3 support, but that one isn't really helpful, since you can't access external storage with the iPad, besides importing photos. I use it occasionally to hook up an Ethernet adapter to transfer files over my network, but setting this up is always more hassle then a simple USB cable would be, especially when I'm not at home. So, although that adapter is a nice perk, it doesn't really fix the problem...

Comment: Considered using a USB-A to USB-A cable to use that adapter to hook up to your PC? ;-)

Comment: No, because that won’t  work. USB is a master/slave based system, meaning that one device has host capability, and another one being the client. Both the iPad and the Computer are host devices, meaning they accept clients like storage media, input devices etc. Without at least one device being able to switch roles (as in USB OTG for example), you can’t connect two hosts. By the way, that’s why USB-A to USB-A cables are non-standard, for USB-A being the host connector. So that isn’t an option as well.

Comment: The iPad is an USB OTG device. It can both act as a host (for example accepting a USB ethernet adapter, USB flash drive, USB microphone, etc.) and as a device (when connecting to a PC or Mac).

Comment: Where did you get that information from? Just checked that by connecting my iPad with the original iPad camera adapter (the new one) to several computers running both linux and mac. Nothing happened, used a 3.0 USB-A to USB-A cable. iPad is not charging, didn't ask me to "trust the computer", not even `dmesg` or `lsusb` indicating that an USB device was detected. So I doubt there is USB-OTG capability in the iPad Camera adapter.

Comment: Edit: It doesn't even matter if there's OTG capability in the camera adapter, since OTG capabilities would not help here. OTG is used for turning a client into a host (e.g. the iPad usually is a USB client to a computer, and now it is a host to some other client, e.g. an USB disk), but not turning a host (the computer the iPad is connected to) into a client. The computer the iPad is connected to is always a host, and for that matter you'd have two hosts connected, at best.

Comment: No, OTG works both ways. The iPad can be either a client or a host. Similarly you can have PCs with OTG ports. I have successfully connected the iPad this way on Linux, but special kernel configuration needed. I used a custom cable, but you could go through a custom adapter if you can easily make one